# Ecto associations from ltree

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a Topics model that form a `hierarchy` with a `parent_id` key. I'd like to quickly be able to access the path without doing recursive selects so there's an additional `hierarchy` field using Postgres ltrees following [this guide](http://hostiledeveloper.com/2016/05/22/ltrees-in-phoenix.html).

```
defmodule App.Topic do
  use App.Web, :model

  schema "topics" do
    field :name, :string
    field :hierarchy, :string
    belongs_to :parent, App.Topic, foreign_key: :parent_id
  end
end
```

The ltree part works fine and looks something like this in the database: `1.2.5` where each numeral is the id of an ancestor topic.

**The question is how can I load a topic, with its ancestor topics preloaded?**

One promising route appeared to be [preload functions](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3) but I could not get it to work. In the controller I had:

```
query = from t in App.Topic, 
  where: fragment("hierarchy @> (SELECT hierarchy FROM topics WHERE id = ?)", ^id)

topic = Repo.get!(Topic, id)
  |> Repo.preload([ancestors: ^query])
```

I added `has_many :ancestors, App.Topic, foreign_key: :parent_id` to get Ecto from complaining about a foreign keys but is probably not correct.